# Can I skip the slow motion "death blow" sequences?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

At first, I thought these sequences were cool, but now they're rather old.  I'd much rather the death blow sequence to just be at normal game speed.  Is there some way to turn these off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a [No Kill Moves](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/33) mod that you can place in your Skyrim data directory. There's no way to turn it off in-game.

Comment: Awesome.  Trying it now.  Will report back soon.

Comment: I've been hacking away at things and haven't seen the slow-mo death blow sequence yet.  However, I was expecting to still see my character's finishing move at regular game speed.  What, exactly, is the purpose of that death blow sequence?  Is it just for show or does it serve as an indicator that your character has delivered a more-powerful-than-usual strike on the enemy?  If I am now seeing the sequence at all, does this mean I am no longer dealing those finishing blows, that perhaps I am missing out on a critical hit?

Comment: It just removes the extra death blow sequence, it doesn't speed it up to normal speed. The sequence usually happens for crits, but it doesn't look like the code affects the crit rate, just when the animation happens, it gets skipped.

Comment: Haven't seen the death blow sequence and have been doing well, so I will mark as answer until someone comes along to say that a vital crit is missed or something.